# Bootstrap not working when deploying a Ruby on Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have placed bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in assets/stylesheets and assets/javascripts, respectively. When I run my app locally, I get the styling that I expect. Further, if I view the source locally I see the following tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/comments.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

(there are many other tags like this one)

I have the same setup on a DigitalOcean Droplet, but the css and javascript doesn't seem to be working.
If I view the source on the server I see tags like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

Something doesn't seem to be rendering properly. This is probably my lack of experience showing, but I really have no idea how to proceed here.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you add the files to `application.css` and `application.js`? Also, did you try runnin `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: Show us how you are linking your bootstrap files in your view (erd, haml, etc.). It seems like the problem is in the way you are linking to your files. Links in production and development are generate different urls.

Comment: Firstly, if you have assets in your app/assets/stylesheets directory then you need to make sure they are listed in the config/initlizers/assets.rb file (there's a default commented out that you can use as an example).  Secondly, you'll need to precompile those assets so they are put in the right directory.  (ie, a copy of them is placed in the public dir and contains a manifest with the asset version) ... As an alternative, have you considered using the bootstrap-sass gem?

Comment: @maxpleaner, I have added the files to application.css and applicaiton.js. I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile (without RAILS_ENV=production). This created an assets dir with some files in it in my public directory, but still no luck; the css isn't loading.

Comment: @trh -> Thanks! It looks like I needed to add the following lines to assets.rb:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.css )
I'm still not sure why this works this way in production, but not when I'm developing. Similarly, on my live server, I can't navigate to assets/application.js the same way i can from localhost:3000/assets/applications.js .... Mind if i ask why this is the case? 

THANKS AGAIN, YOU'VE SAVED MY SANITY